# Phonegap's Android emulator launch results in error

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm trying to launch Phonegap's Android emulator in my project directory with the following command.

> phonegap run android --emulator

It results in the following error.

> Error: ENOTDIR, not a directory
>   '/usr/local/bin/android/tools/lib/build.template'

I could not find any solutions for this on the internet.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you open emulator using android tools? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/android.html

Comment: Yes, executing 'android avd' command and launching my emulator from there.

Answer (score -1):

i suggest you to use cordova : http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/